# iPhone glShaderBinary

Tags: iphone, shader, opengl-es-2.0

Does anyone have an example of how to compile a shader, save the shader binary, and use glShaderBinary to later load the shader with iPhone/iOS (OpenGL ES 2.0)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to do this (at least with iOS 4 and below). iOS doesn't support any precompiled binary shaders. If you query OpenGL for the number of binary shader formats it supports, you get back zero.

You're forced to compile the shaders every time you start the app.

(Answered my own question.)

Answer (score 0):

The best place to start is the XCode OpenGL template project, which for some time has included ES 2.0 shaders by default. It also has the distinct advantage of being a very, very simple example.

Comment: Thanks, I checked out the template project, but it doesn't use glShaderBinary().  Instead, it compiles the shaders from source code every time the app starts.

Comment: Sorry - you may like to look at the website for the 'Programming with OpenGL ES2.0' book. I've only just started my way through the print version, but the website should have sample code for iOS that may be useful to you. http://opengles-book.com/